# WebView inside PersistentBottomSheet doesn't detect vertical scroll

Tags: flutter

WebView doesn't detect Vertical Scroll inside a PersistentBottomSheetController because it uses scroll down to close the bottom sheet.

I Have no problem using a ListView inside a PersistentBottomSheetController. ListView correctly detect scroll and the bottom sheet doesn't move.

WebView shows up and cover the entire space correctly, clicks work fine, scroll doesn't. scroll up does nothing, scroll down closes the bottom sheet.

Note that i'm using:

```dart
gestureRecognizers: Set()
..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                                        () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer()))
```

```dart
PersistentBottomSheetController<void> showModal(
    {BuildContext context, Widget child}) {
  return
    showBottomSheet<void>(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: WHITE_RICE,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(30.0)),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      spreadRadius: -10.0,
                      blurRadius: 80.0,
                      color: GRAY_MOUSE,
                      offset: Offset(0, -50)),
                ]),
            child: FractionallySizedBox(
              heightFactor: 0.95,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, bottom: 4.0),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 30,
                      height: 5,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: GRAY_SNOW_DARK,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.5),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              width: 48,
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: RegularText(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                path2: 'cafepage_cell2_modal_title',
                                text: 'Cancellation Policy',
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color: GRAY_IRON,
                              ),
                            ),
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 16.0),
                                child: IconXDark(),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        Divider(),
                        Expanded(
                          child: FutureBuilderSimplified(
                            future: TranslationsSingleton()
                                .getText('user_app', 'cafepage_cell2_modal_link'),
                            builder: (context, t) => WebView(
                                  initialUrl: t.data,
                                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                                  gestureRecognizers: Set()
                                    ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                                        () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
                                ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        })
  ;
}
```